# RVO and returning to vectors, reusing capacity

Tags: c++

I have a question about what I can expect out of RVO (I know there are no guarantees until C++17). For the following example:

```
std::vector<Foo> getFooVectorFromSomewhere();

class A
{
private:
    std::vector<Foo> foo_;
public:
    void doSomething()
    {
        foo_ = getFooVectorFromSomewhere();
    }
}
```

I am trying to cut down on the amount of memory allocation/deallocation occuring in a particularly hot-spot of the code. Will the above allow `getFooVectorFromSomewhere()` to reuse `foo_`'s capactity, or will this result in memory allocation everytime? I would like to stay away from passing `foo_` by reference and clearing it inside the function if possible for code clarity's sake. (In this case foo_ strictly is an output, I just want to clear it and reuse it if possible).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elision (RVO) only applies, for the return from a function call, if you are directly using that to *initialize* an object. Since `foo_` already exists, elision doesn't apply.

At the moment that assignment statement executes, you have two `vector`s: `foo_`, and the prvalue returned from `getFooVectorFromSomewhere`. Each of those `vector`s may have their own allocations.

The most efficient way to handle this is to destroy whatever allocation is in `foo_` and move the allocation from the prvalue into that object. And... that is exactly what will happen (in C++11). This is called "move assignment". It involves destroying everything in `foo_`, followed by a few pointer copies and null-ing out of pointers.

If this is pre-C++11, then it's going to have to copy from one `vector` to the other. If it does so, then it may reuse the allocation in `foo_` if it is large enough. And if it's not, then it's going to have to make a bigger one.

> Is there any way in C++11 that the compiler could realize that the allocation of foo_ will be destroyed and attempt to reuse that capacity inside of the function (as long as it has enough capacity obviously) before making a new allocation and moving the result at the end of the function?

No. Assigning the return value of a function to a variable does not cause the compiler to make that variable somehow part of a function's interface, so that the function can access and manipulate it. That's part of why elision only applies to *initializing* objects, not arbitrary assignment to existing objects. The function effectively acts on uninitialized memory, but it can only act on that memory by initializing it. Named RVO allows the function to do post-initialization work, but initialization of it is part and parcel of what it does.

If you want a function to manipulate a live object in such a way, it needs to be an *explicit* part of the function's interface, passed as a parameter.

Comment: Is there any way in C++11 that the compiler could realize that the allocation of foo_ will be destroyed and attempt to reuse that capacity inside of the function (as long as it has enough capacity obviously) before making a new allocation and moving the result at the end of the function? I'm not worried about it being able to move the result into foo_, I'm just trying to avoid deallocating foo_'s internal buffer and then reallocating a new buffer inside the function which will then be moved back.

Comment: @RyanP: ... what? Are you suggesting that `getFooVectorFromSomewhere` will magically know that its return value will be used on a live object, and that it will magically go and talk to that object, absconding with its memory for some process? No, that doesn't happen. Whatever return value that function creates will have its own storage, unless the function is explicitly written to hunt down `foo_` and explicitly absconds with its storage. And it will do that whether you assign the return value to `foo_` or not.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm asking. I understand that's a far stretch, I guess I'm really asking if there is anything that occurs during optimization or linking that would allow for that. I can pass the vector by reference, clear it at the top of the function, and proceed. It just doesn't make the resulting code as readable (to me at least, code intention is more obvious to me when outputs are on the left). It just seems that if a vector is being deallocated to make way for another of the same type, its cap could be reused. Wasn't sure if the linker/optimizer would do that. It seems no

Answer (score 0):

I see that misconception over and over again. C++17 **DOES NOT** guarantee (N)RVO! I have no idea where this misconception stems from, but a lot of people share this. C++17 guarantees copy elision in some cases, but (N)RVO is **not** one of them.

In your case, there will be no NRVO at all! Here, `std::vector` move assingment will kick in. (N)RVO could be discussed in context of your `getFooVectorFromSomewhere`, but since the code is not provided, discussion can't take place.

Comment: This isn't NRVO of any kind. NRVO refers to returning a variable that is a local variable of a function. This is about assigning a returned prvalue to an object.

Comment: @NicolBolas, and how is it different from what I just said?

Comment: Because you're talking about this as though the problem is that C++17 does not guarantee NRVO. But this isn't a case of NRVO, so it doesn't matter if C++17 guarantees it or not.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I am adressing what OP said in the beginning of the question, because it is important to understand, and I see a lot of confusion on this matter.

Comment: Also, C++17 does guarantee basic return value elision: the specific case of the return expression being a prvalue. That's typically what is discussed when people talk about RVO as separate from NRVO. So by that metric, C++17 does guarantee RVO, but not NRVO.

Comment: @NicolBolas, agree. I also do not think I said anything which contradicts that.

Comment: It's mostly that you put "N" in parenthesis. That suggests that the "named" part is optional, and thus the statement is saying that C++17 doesn't guarantee Named or Unnamed RVO.

Comment: @NicolBolas, this is just a habit I acquired since I've noticed people started using RVO and NRVO almost interchangeably - to highlight the difference between it.

Answer (score 0):

The code `foo_ = getFooVectorFromSomewhere();` will use the *Move Assignment* operator associated with `std::vector`. If your implementation optimizes this operator properly, then it will simply swap the pointers associated with the old and new buffers, and avoid memory allocation altogether.

It's not clear what this code is meant to replace, however, and we can't make guarantees/assessments about whether it will improve performance without seeing what it's replacing.